# mysqlpp query not returning from execution

Tags: mysql++

I have a fairly simple call I'm trying to make to a database.  I have everything surrounded in try/catch and if statements, but... nothing.  I know I'm making the connection (the connection refcount in MySQL increments each time I try running the script), but it never seems to return.  Code is:

```
 if (!conn.connect(db, server, username, pass))
 { /* Log error to a file */}
 try
 {
     mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query();
     query << "CALL db.test('1', '2')";
     std::cout << "About to call query" << std::endl;
     if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store())
     {
        std::string toReturn = "";
        res[0][0].to_string(toReturn);
        std::cout << "Query called.  Result: " << toReturn << std::endl;
     }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 { /*Output caught exception*/ }
```

and I get:

```
    About to call query
```

as my sole output.
I have more debugging in there (query is being put together correctly, connection is correct, etc).
Anyone have any idea what might be happening, or what I should check next?

Thanks!

-- Edit: If I run the call straight from MySQL, everything works as expected, so that's not causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the query inside conn.query(); Like

```
std::cout << "About to call query" << std::endl;
mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query("CALL db.test('1', '2')");
if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store())
{
   std::string toReturn = "";      //this is not necessary
   res[0][0].to_string(toReturn);  //this is not necessary

   for (size_t i = 0; i < res.num_rows(); ++i) 
   {
        std::cout << "Query called.  Result: " << res[i][0] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

you can refer http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html for examples